# Sorting an array of strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have learned two array sorting methods in Ruby:

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array.sort.reverse!
```

or:

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
array.sort { |x,y| y<=>x }
```

And I am not able to differentiate between the two. Which method is better and how exactly are they different in execution?

Comment: Such a hairy question. It's the same method `#sort`, and for implementation deatils, feel free to check C source code, http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort.

Comment: Aside: If you need a datastructure in Ruby that supports most of the Enumerable methods and sorts and stores unique data, you might want to look at SortedSet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Both lines do the same (create a new array, which is reverse sorted). The main argument is about readability and performance. `array.sort.reverse!` is more readable than `array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}` - I think we can agree here.

For the performance part, I created a quick benchmark script, which gives the following on my system (`ruby 1.9.3p392 [x86_64-linux]`):

```
                              user     system      total        real
array.sort.reverse        1.330000   0.000000   1.330000 (  1.334667)
array.sort.reverse!       1.200000   0.000000   1.200000 (  1.198232)
array.sort!.reverse!      1.200000   0.000000   1.200000 (  1.199296)
array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}   5.220000   0.000000   5.220000 (  5.239487)
```

Run times are pretty constant for multiple executions of the benchmark script.

`array.sort.reverse` (with or without `!`) is way faster than `array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}`. Thus, I recommend that.

---

Here is the script as a Reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do|b|
  master = (1..1_000_000).map(&:to_s).shuffle
  a = master.dup
  b.report("array.sort.reverse      ") do
    a.sort.reverse
  end

  a = master.dup
  b.report("array.sort.reverse!     ") do
    a.sort.reverse!
  end

  a = master.dup
  b.report("array.sort!.reverse!    ") do
    a.sort!.reverse!
  end

  a = master.dup
  b.report("array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x} ") do
    a.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}
  end
end
```

Comment: One minor refinement is to create the array one time: `master = (1..1000000).map(&:to_s).shuffle` and then set `a = master.clone` before each benchmark report, so they're all sorting exactly the same thing.  I also boosted the size to 1_000_000, and added a benchmark for `a.sort!.reverse!`.  On my system (`ruby 2.0.0p195 [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`) using in-place `a.sort!.reverse!` came out the winner.

Comment: `reverse!` in this answer is wasting CPU. It's trying to modify a temporary array created when `sort` handed its array off, which doesn't help.

Comment: @pjs, somewhere on SO I have a large benchmark testing various ways of doing a descending sort. `reverse` is faster than using `sort_by` or `sort` with reversed or negated results in the block, which surprised us. `sort!.reverse!` is faster because its mutating the original array.

Comment: @theTinMan - makes perfect sense to me.  That's why I added that specific benchmark when I tried it out.

Comment: @pjs I applied your suggestion. Interestingly `array.sort.reverse!` is slightly faster for `1.9.3`.

Comment: @tessi - Looking at your benchmark, it appears you changed the label but not the actual code.  I expect that to have an impact based on Tin Man's reasoning.

Comment: @pjs Thanks. There is a time, when it is too late to write code and one should better go to bed :)

Answer (score 7):

There really is no difference here. Both methods return a new array.

For the purposes of this example, simpler is better. I would recommend `array.sort.reverse` because it is much more readable than the alternative. Passing blocks to methods like `sort` should be saved for arrays of more complex data structures and user-defined classes.

Edit: While `destructive` methods (anything ending in a !) are good for performance games, it was pointed out that they aren't **required** to return an updated array, or anything at all for that matter. It is important to keep this in mind because `array.sort.reverse!` could very likely return `nil`. If you wish to use a destructive method on a newly generated array, you should prefer calling `.reverse!` on a separate line instead of having a one-liner.

Example:

```
array = array.sort
array.reverse!
```

should be preferred to

```
array = array.sort.reverse!
```

Comment: The OP is just learning Ruby and shouldn't be so anal about performance at this stage. I stand by my recommendation.

Comment: @JamesBrewer however calling destructive reverse on temporary Array created with previous sort is a bad practice. There is nowhere documented `reverse!` has to return an updated array. It has only update the called object. The former is a task of the non-destructive version.

Answer (score 3):

### Reverse! is Faster

There's often no substitute for benchmarking. While it probably makes no difference in shorter scripts, the #reverse! method is significantly faster than sorting using the "spaceship" operator. For example, on MRI Ruby 2.0, and given the following benchmark code:

```
require 'benchmark'

array = ["one", "two", "three"]
loops = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|
    bm.report('reverse!')  { loops.times {array.sort.reverse!} }
    bm.report('spaceship') { loops.times {array.sort {|x,y| y<=>x} }}
end
```

the system reports that #reverse! is almost twice as fast as using the combined comparison operator.

```
                user     system      total        real
reverse!    0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.344198)
spaceship   0.590000   0.010000   0.600000 (  0.595747)
```

My advice: use whichever is more semantically meaningful in a given context, unless you're running in a tight loop.

Comment: It's actually an x-wing :)

Answer (score 2):

With comparison as simple as your example, there is not much difference, but as the formula for comparison gets complicated, it is better to avoid using `<=>` with a block because the block you pass will be evaluated for each element of the array, causing redundancy. Consider this:

```
array.sort{|x, y| some_expensive_method(x) <=> some_expensive_method(y)}
```

In this case, `some_expensive_method` will be evaluated for each possible pair of element of `array`.

In your particular case, use of a block with `<=>` can be avoided with `reverse`.

```
array.sort_by{|x| some_expensive_method(x)}.reverse
```

This is called Schwartzian transform.

Comment: How do you "reverse sort" with `sort_by`? Because that's what OP is doing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the term 'Schartzian transform' - didn't know this pattern has a name :)

Answer (score 2):

In playing with tessi's benchmarks on my machine, I've gotten some interesting results.  I'm running `ruby 2.0.0p195 [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`, i.e., latest release of Ruby 2 on an OS X system.  I used [bmbm](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bmbm) rather than `bm` from the Benchmark module.  My timings are:

```
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------------------------
array.sort.reverse:         1.010000   0.000000   1.010000 (  1.020397)
array.sort.reverse!:        0.810000   0.000000   0.810000 (  0.808368)
array.sort!.reverse!:       0.800000   0.010000   0.810000 (  0.809666)
array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}:    0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.291002)
array.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x}:   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.105345)
---------------------------------------------------- total: 3.030000sec

                                user     system      total        real
array.sort.reverse:         0.210000   0.000000   0.210000 (  0.208378)
array.sort.reverse!:        0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.027746)
array.sort!.reverse!:       0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.020082)
array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}:    0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.107065)
array.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x}:   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.105359)
```

First, note that in the Rehearsal phase that `sort!` using a comparison block comes in as the clear winner.  Matz must have tuned the heck out of it in Ruby 2!

The other thing that I found exceedingly weird was how much improvement `array.sort.reverse!` and `array.sort!.reverse!` exhibited in the production pass.  It was so extreme it made me wonder whether I had somehow screwed up and passed these already sorted data, so I added explicit checks for sorted or reverse-sorted data prior to performing each benchmark.

---

My variant of tessi's script follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'benchmark'

class Array
  def sorted?
    (1...length).each {|i| return false if self[i] < self[i-1] }
    true
  end

  def reversed?
    (1...length).each {|i| return false if self[i] > self[i-1] }
    true
  end
end

master = (1..1_000_000).map(&:to_s).shuffle

Benchmark.bmbm(25) do|b|
  a = master.dup
  puts "uh-oh!" if a.sorted?
  puts "oh-uh!" if a.reversed?
  b.report("array.sort.reverse:") { a.sort.reverse }

  a = master.dup
  puts "uh-oh!" if a.sorted?
  puts "oh-uh!" if a.reversed?
  b.report("array.sort.reverse!:") { a.sort.reverse! }

  a = master.dup
  puts "uh-oh!" if a.sorted?
  puts "oh-uh!" if a.reversed?
  b.report("array.sort!.reverse!:") { a.sort!.reverse! }

  a = master.dup
  puts "uh-oh!" if a.sorted?
  puts "oh-uh!" if a.reversed?
  b.report("array.sort{|x,y| y<=>x}:") { a.sort{|x,y| y<=>x} }

  a = master.dup
  puts "uh-oh!" if a.sorted?
  puts "oh-uh!" if a.reversed?
  b.report("array.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x}:") { a.sort!{|x,y| y<=>x} }
end
```