# How does one put strings alphabetically in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am trying to sort a series of strings from an array alphabetically. What would be the easiest way to do that in ruby with a loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637869/sorting-an-array-of-strings-in-ruby

Comment: If the strings are in an `Array`, just use `my_array.sort`.

Comment: The easiest way would be to not use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `Array#sort`?

eg

```
array = ["ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "ddd"]
array.sort
# => ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```